# Ordenar alfabéticamente un Array ignorando mayúsculas

Tags: javascript, array

Ordenar un *Array*   `var arrayx = ['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'];` quiero que se ordené de la siguiente forma

> AaBb.

Intenté con `sort()`, pero toma en cuenta las mayúsculas y lo ordena como `ABab.` Quisiera saber cómo  puedo hacer para ordenarlo sin tomar en cuenta las mayúsculas.

Nota: El *Array* es variable, sus valores los agrega el usuario, así que sería mejor con una fórmula general, que aplique a todos los casos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin argumentos, la función `Array.prototype.sort()` ordenará utilizando el valor Unicode de cada carácter, de menor a mayor. Por ejemplo, el valor Unicode de `A` es `U+0041`, el de `B` es `U+0042`, el de `a` es `U+0061` y el de `b` es `U+0062`. En orden, `A`, `B`, `a` y `b`.

No obstante `sort()` puede recibir una función que define algún otro orden. Esta función toma dos argumentos que corresponden con dos valores del arreglo que se estén ordenando en ese momento. Por ejemplo, `a` y `b`. Para este caso, bastaría con:

```js
var array = ['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  var n = a.toLocaleLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLocaleLowerCase());
  return n === 0 && a !== b ? b.localeCompare(a) : n;
});

console.log(array.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve un problema similar hace poco pero en angular, es básicamente lo mismo:

```
 var array = ['A', 'b', 'a', 'B'];

 array=array.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.toLowerCase()> b.toLowerCase()) {
    return 1;
  } else if(a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Considera dar una explicación, las respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad.

Answer (score 0):

También podrías hacer esto:

```js
public static ordenarStrings<T>(v: T[], key: string): T[] {
    return v.sort((a, b) => {
      let n = a[key].toLocaleLowerCase().localeCompare(b[key].toLocaleLowerCase());
      return n === 0 && a !== b ? b[key].localeCompare(a[key]) : n;
    });
  }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué? ¿Cómo funciona?